# Keep certain routes rendered with react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a routing table that looks something like this on the top level:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/foo" exact component={...} />
  <Route path="/bar" exact component={...} />
  <Route path="/" exact component={...} />
  <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

This works fine where those 3 are three distinct pages that once one renders the other should not. However, I have a few routes that I want to add that should render on top of any other route.

To be more specific; I have a settings page, `/settings`, that when visited, opens up an overlay that should render on top of the previous route.

The behaviour I'm after might be a bit confusing programatically, because if I'm on `/foo` and want to render `/settings`, I want the url to change to `/settings` and not `/foo/settings` but still render the content of `/foo` behind `/settings`. If you were to visit the link directly (not by navigating in the app) you would end up having `/` rendered in the background and `/settings` on top.

I have yet to come up with a straight forward way of doing this. In version 2/3 I stored the previous children and kept those rendered (which was a bit messy and quite ugly).

Any ideas are much welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you I would not involved router to achieve this behaviour, instead I would use query string to activate settings component above any route.

Comment: That is an alternative. But after having thought about it there is no clean solution to it and I would urge anyone attempting something similar to re-think their approach.